# How do I check what plugins are enabled on an eosio single local testnode, without stopping it?

Tags: cleos, history, plugin, single-node

I want to check if my history_plugin and history_api_plugin is running and which options are enabled.

How do I check this from cleos ?
Also, can I enable history_plugin without replaying or stopping the nodeos ?

Comment: As a better practice, you should always enable plugins from config.ini, so you can always check there which plugins are enabled and which are disabled.

Comment: Btw, You are using which version of eos, history_plugin is deprecated

Comment: My nodeos version is 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct way, but you can check whether `***_api_plugin` is activated by calling `/v1/node/get_supported_apis`. Run the next command in command line (in the case of local testnet). You should stop nodeos first to toggle plugin activation.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/node/get_supported_apis
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work.